# "Nicht" in Nebensätzen mit vielen Verben am Ende

Tags: word-order

Welches davon ist korrekt:

> ... dass ich mein Auto nicht habe waschen lassen.
>
> ... dass ich mein Auto habe nicht waschen lassen.

oder vll. beides?

**Edit:** Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass der zweite Satz sowas wie "nicht waschen, sondern lackieren" impliziert, und der erste einfach eine Aussage mit sich bringt, dass am Auto womöglich nichts gemacht wurde.

Die Frage rührt daher, dass ich mal im Unterricht gehört habe, die ganze Verbgruppe sollte am Satzende zusammengehalten werden. Demnach wäre der zweite Satz falsch. Ob es wirklich so ist? Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass beide Sätze korrekt sind, aber der zweite etwas anderes betont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rein technisch ist beides richtig, da "nicht" quasi ein Adverb ist. Das kannst du als Adverbiale zum gesamten Verbkomplex sehen oder eher als Adverbiale zu "waschen lassen". Der Unterschied ist in den meisten Kontexten wohl klein.

> …, dass ich mein Auto [manchmal/nicht/mit Kuhmilch] habe [manchmal/nicht/mit Kuhmilch] waschen lassen.

Im obigen Satz mit "nicht" bietet sich eher eine Verneinung des gesamten Verbs an, also vor "haben", da sonst spezifisch das "Waschen" verneint würde.

> ... dass mein Auto habe nicht waschen sondern wachsen lassen.

In Bezug auf "Verbalgruppe zusammenhalten" muss ich sagen, dass ich denke, dass damit genau nicht diese Sonderstrukturen gemeint sind, sondern Sachen wie

> … dass man vom Blatt spielen können muss.

Die Aussage ist an sich aber fragwürdig, da die Frage, was genau zu einer Verbgruppe gehört, eben oft genau keine eindeutige Antwort hat.

> … dass ich mir [eine Pizza] habe [eine Pizza] kommen lassen.
>   … dass ich mir [die Haare] habe [die Haare] schneiden lassen.

Im ersten Satz klingt die Version mit Pizza vor "haben" besser, im zweiten würde ich zu "Haare" vor "schneiden" tendieren, einfach weil "Haare schneiden" sehr fix ist.

Comment: Der Unterschied bei den letzten Beispiele ist, dass "die Haare schneiden" ein fester Ausdruck ist, "die Pizza kommen" aber nicht. Somit ist "die Haare" wichtiger Bestandteil. So oder so, nach meinem Sprachgefühl muss "nicht", "eine Pizza" oder "die Haare" vor "habe"

Comment: Und bezüglich deinem ergänzenden Beispiel, würde ich es auch mit "nicht" davor, also wiefolgt, sagen/schreiben: "..., dass ich mein Auto nicht habe waschen sondern wachsen lassen."

Comment: @Em1... ja, geht alles. Ist nur ein Frage der Betonung. Was "die Haare" angeht, das ist reine Konvention. Wenn ich jeden Abend Pizza bestelle, dann wird das fürmich und meine Familie genauso eine feste Wendung. Ich denke nicht, dass man da eine zu strikte Trennung machen sollte/kann.

Comment: @Em1... wie wär's mit "... dass ich ihm habe die Leviten lesen lassen" Würdest du "Leviten" hier auch nach vorne setzen?

Comment: Ja, würde ich. – Zu dem genannten Thema finde ich leider nichts, aber [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882) hat trotzdem eine Reihe an Beispielen. Es geht zwar wie gesagt um was anderes, aber die Beispiele folgen alle dem, was imho ja zumindest natürlicher ist: "nachdem sie uns nicht haben einladen wollen" - "bevor du das Glas hast fallen lassen" - "weil sie euch haben ankommen sehen" uvm. In all den Beispiel kann ich mir vorstellen, dass jmd diese vertauscht und es klingt nicht schrecklich, aber ist imho falsch.

Comment: Mein Punkt ist glaube ich, das Verb bzw. die Verben gehören nach hinten. Und zwar zusammen. Das Hilfsverb trennt sich nur, wenn du das ganze umformuliert ("er sagte, ich habe ihm die haare schneiden lassen"). Rutscht es auch nach hinten ("er sagte, dass ich das getan habe") wird es von letzter Position nur eben durch solche Konstruktion, wie hier Thema ist, verdrängt. Dann bleibt es trotzdem in der geschlossenen Verbgruppe hinter allem andere.

Comment: @Em1... das Ding ist, dass die Idee einer "geschlossenen verbgruppe" vor der Realität nicht besteht. "Eine Pizza bestellt habe ich gestern. Heute will ich das nicht" Hier bildet "bestellen zusammen mit dem Objekt eine Konstituente, es ist nur eine Frage der Interpretation. Noch ein extremeres Beispiel "Den Müll auf den Hof gestellt habe ich gestern." Angesichts solcher Formulierungen (die grammatisch einwandfrei sind) wäre es schlicht widersprüchlich zu behaupten, dass hinter dem "habe" nichts stehen darf, denn zu Grunde liegt immer die Frage wie man gruppiert und das obliegt dem Sprecher

Comment: ... für viele Sätze ist es auf jeden Fall unidiomatisch aber eine generelle Regel halte ich (wie fast immer bei Deutscher Satzstruktur) für unangemessen.

Comment: Nun ja, deine Beispiele sind was ganz anderes und "habe" hat in diesen Sätze eh nichts an letzter Stelle verloren.

Comment: @Em1... es ging mir mit diesen Beispielen darum, zu zeigen, dass direkte Objekte teils sehr eng mit ihrem Verb verknüpft sein können, selbst wenn es sich nicht um eine fixe Phrase handelt. Diese Verknüpfung kann dann auch so eng sein, dass sie dazu führt, dass ein Objekt zwischen "habe" und dem Rest steht (in einem Beispiel wie dem von OP)